# Google Earth Engine, export image to drive returns EEException: Request payload size exceeds the limit: 10485760 bytes

Tags: google-earth-engine, geemap

I run a model in GEE and I am trying to export the result using:

```
geemap.ee_export_image_to_drive(classified, description="Test_run_raster.tif", max_pixels=10**13, scale=20, 
                                region=India.geometry().bounds())
```

and I get the following error.

```
EEException: Request payload size exceeds the limit: 10485760 bytes.
```

I've even tried to export the result using a higher scale, but it returns the same error.

I am using GEE for startup's.

Any idea of how to fix this?

Comment: This “Request payload size” error indicates that some of the data that would be used to *compute* your image — not the image itself — is too large to be processed. Please provide a complete script that can be used to reproduce the problem — that will help us locate the problematic part.

Comment: What I am doing is to use a large shp to train a model for a machine learning application. This shp is loaded from my local drive. Is there any other way to load shp in GEE in python?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to say that and to give more complete code (including the part where you are loading the shape file).